# How to scroll two div elements at the same time

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to scroll two div at the same time, and the divs are in a jquery ui dialog.
I want to detect its scroll event, and then I could scroll them at the same time. but I fail at the first step.
the dialog html is:

```
<div>
    <div id="div1" style="width=3px; overflow-x:scroll;">hello, world ...</div>
    <div id="div2" style="width=3px; overflow-x:scroll;">hello, world ...</div>
</div>
```

the dialog js is:

```
$(ret).dialog({
    width: 100,
    height: 120
});
```

the content of ret is the dialog html, and I get it by using .ajax().

the scroll function is:

```
$(document).on('scroll', 'div[id=1]', function() { alert("get it!"); }
```

unfortunately, the scroll function does not work.
however, it works if I change 'scroll' to 'click'. I don't know why, could you help me? thank you!

```
$(document).on('click', 'div[id=1]', function() { alert("get it!"); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach the scroll event directly to the scrolled element and get the position values using: `scrollTop()`, `scrollLeft()`. Here is a quick example:

[**JSnippet Demo**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/332/Scrolling-two-divs-at-the-same-time)

```
$(function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    $("#dialog div").on('scroll', function(e) { 
        var ele = $(e.currentTarget);
        var left = ele.scrollLeft();
        var top = ele.scrollTop();
        if (ele.attr("id") === 'div1') {
            $("#div2").scrollTop(top);
            $("#div2").scrollLeft(left);
        } else {
            $("#div1").scrollTop(top);
            $("#div1").scrollLeft(left);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it says `dialog` is not a function

Comment: @CodeIt It works fine in the demo - Don't forget to include jQueryUI lib...