# Single scroll for 2 same layouts in different div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have  2 divs with table like structure on a page. I want to make them responsive and currently the only way is to put  horizontal scroll after a certain point .The divs are in different wrappers/container so can't move them in a single wrapper. **My problem is I want only one horizontall scroll rather than two. What is the best way to do this?** so that they have one scroll to move both horizontally.

> Below is what I am trying (the issue)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.ScrollWrapper1 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  float: left;
}
.ScrollWrapper2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.TableHead {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  width: calc(10% - 1px);
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc
}

.marginTop40 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.ScrollWrapper h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

@media(max-width:1024px) {
  .TableHead {
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ScrollWrapper1">
<h1>Div on page with table format</h1>
  <div class="TableHead">
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="ScrollWrapper2 marginTop40">
  <h1>Another div on page with table format</h1>
  <div class="TableHead">
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you can't alter the HTML you may have to use JS --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537316/how-to-scroll-two-div-elements-at-the-same-time

Comment: Yes it helped me @ovokuro . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get scroll left of currently scrolling div and then bind it to other div

```js
$('.ScrollWrapper').on('scroll', function(){
  var _left = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $('.ScrollWrapper').scrollLeft(_left)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.ScrollWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.TableHead {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  width: calc(10% - 1px);
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc
}

.marginTop40 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.ScrollWrapper h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

@media(max-width:1024px) {
  .TableHead {
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ScrollWrapper">
<h1>Div on page with table format</h1>
  <div class="TableHead">
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>
    <div class="row">Table 1</div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="ScrollWrapper marginTop40">
  <h1>Another div on page with table format</h1>
  <div class="TableHead">
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>
    <div class="row">Table 2</div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhishek..Also to @ovokuro for pointing to the correct example code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, @ovokuro is also good but too lengthy in this case.

Comment: He gave me a link to the answer but you actually answered it. Keep up the good work pandey ji :P