# Sync scrolling between two divs - first div horizontal and the other verticalli

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im working on a website for some client. And I want to achieve that when you scroll on the page another div scrolls to right.

[image]

So as you see the above div has white-space:nowrap; and overflow-x:scroll
When they get to an anchor point the 'about' gets the class active. But I want to sync them so if you get on the about anchor the about goes to the left.

```
 <ul class="subnavigation__list">
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link">item 1</a>
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link  active">item 2</a>
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link">item 3</a>       
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link">item 4</a>
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link">item 5</a>
   <li class="subnavigation__item"><a class="subnavigation__link">item 6</a>
 </ul>
```

Any ideas? I dont know where to start!

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://scrollmagic.io/

Comment: No, not quite. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253474/single-scroll-for-2-same-layouts-in-different-div/43253866#43253866)*** what you want?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey About right! did some tuning on the script and it worked perfectly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single scroll for 2 same layouts in different div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253474/single-scroll-for-2-same-layouts-in-different-div)