# Scroll Two Elements Congruently

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working...

```
var subCatContainer = $(".scroll-me");

subCatContainer.scroll(function() {
    subCatContainer.scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

The two elements I'm trying to get to scroll together are #page and #main on this page: https://aromapoetry.com/candles/chakras/

The JS is in core.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll two div elements at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537316/how-to-scroll-two-div-elements-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I tried that one also.

Comment: You have two version of jquery included on your site.  v1.12 and v1.11

Comment: That would affect this? The other jquery functions work