# Is it possible scroll two divs together vertical but not horizontal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying two make two divs next to each other scrollable vertical together and one div horizontal but the other div should be fixed.

Here is a fiddle where I'm trying to solve it:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/2uf17yx4/9/`
```

the description part should be static and the item part scrollable;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to scroll two div elements at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537316/how-to-scroll-two-div-elements-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow: hidden; to your content__description class.