# scrollTo cannot scroll two elements separately

Tags: javascript, scroll

Say you have many elements aligned horizontally:

```
<div
      id="abc"
      style="display: flex; flex-direction:row; overflow:scroll; height: 100px"
    >
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
       ...
</div>
```

to scroll automatically, you can use some sort of loop like so:

```
self.setInterval(() => {
        if (container.scrollLeft !== scrollWidth) {
          container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
        }
```

This works fine. But now, say you want to scroll 2 separate divs...

```
     for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
          const container = document.getElementById(containers[i]);

          const ScrollWidth = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;

          if (i % 2 == 0) {
            console.log("starting w/ offset!");
            container.scrollTo(ScrollWidth - 1, 0);
          }

          var scrollDirection = 1;
          var scrollLeft = ScrollWidth;
          self.setInterval(() => {
            if (scrollDirection == 1 && container.scrollLeft !== ScrollWidth) {
              container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
            } else if (scrollDirection == -1 && container.scrollLeft !== 0) {
              container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft - 1, 0);
            } else {
              scrollDirection = scrollDirection * -1;
            }
          }, 15);
        }
      });
```

The expected result is that one div should scroll to the left, the other to the right. However, this doesn't work, despite the containers being different. [There is an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537316/how-to-scroll-two-div-elements-at-the-same-time) which suggests to scrollTo off of the element, which I am doing:

```
container.scrollTo(container.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
```

[I reproduced this in sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-thunder-mgrkx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) To quickly test, uncomment one of these 3 lines

```
// var containers = ["cba"];

  // var containers = ["abc"];

  // var containers = ["abc","cba"];
```

Lines 1 & 2 work, however, 3 fails. It seems like scrollTo cannot operate on two separate divs at once. Is this true? If so, what are my options for scrolling both separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the scrolling but with the scope, of your vars.
You have to pass them as parameters in your interval-function because the scope-var ScrollWidth and container get manipulated in the for loop and so you change your references inside your arrow-function:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <div
      id="abc"
      style="display: flex; flex-direction:row; overflow:scroll; height: 100px"
    >
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
    </div>
    <div
      id="cba"
      style="display: flex; flex-direction:row; overflow:scroll; height: 100px"
    >
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
      <h1>Turtles R Cool!</h1>
    </div>
    <script>
      //var containers = ["cba"];
      //var containers = ["abc"];
      var containers = ["abc", "cba"];
      var scrollDirections = [1, 1];

      window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
          const container = document.getElementById(containers[i]);

          const ScrollWidth = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;

          if (i % 2 == 0) {
            console.log("starting w/ offset!");
            container.scrollTo(ScrollWidth - 1, 0);
          }

          self.setInterval(
            (cont, width, offset) => {
              if (scrollDirections[offset] == 1 && cont.scrollLeft !== width) {
                console.log(
                  "Scrolling to the right = " +
                    cont.scrollLeft +
                    " width = " +
                    width
                );
                cont.scrollTo(cont.scrollLeft + 1, 0);
              } else if (
                scrollDirections[offset] == -1 &&
                cont.scrollLeft !== 0
              ) {
                console.log(
                  "Scrolling to the left = " +
                    cont.scrollLeft +
                    " width = " +
                    width
                );
                cont.scrollTo(cont.scrollLeft - 1, 0);
              } else {
                console.log(
                  "Flipping direction left = " +
                    cont.scrollLeft +
                    " width = " +
                    width
                );
                scrollDirections[offset] = scrollDirections[offset] * -1;
              }
            },
            15,
            container,
            ScrollWidth,
            i
          );
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused... I create new variables on each iteration of the loop. You're saying that the variables are function-scoped not loop-scoped?

Comment: They are loop scoped, but transfered as references into your arrow-function (cont, width, offset) =>
And for example "container" references the first element but after the second run of your for-loop it references the second element.
You have now 2 arrow-functions referencing the second element (div)